# Ignite only searches bounding box

Tags: ignite, jts

I am trying to use the geometry search of apache ignite, applying the example almost as given at https://github.com/dmagda/geospatial/blob/master/src/main/java/org/geospatial/SpatialQueryExample.java

However the search does not look like it is taking into account the polygon but rather the bounding box of the polygon.

I am applying:

```
SqlQuery<Long, EndDevicePosition> query = new SqlQuery<>(EndDevicePosition.class, "devEUI=? and geoCoordinates && ?");
    query.setArgs(devEUI, "POLYGON(("+long1+" "+lat1+", "+long2+" "+lat2+", "+long3+" "+lat3+", "+long4+" "+lat4+", "+long1+" "+lat1+"))");

    Collection<Entry<Long, EndDevicePosition>> entries = endDevicePosition.query(query).getAll();
```

on data:

```
lat1    48.93677638153757
lat2    48.935514830810355
lat3    48.9355007350914
lat4    48.93569455087813
long1   2.242525877426105
long2   2.2392808748500586
long3   2.240080057302674
long4   2.241281512801883
```

Though those are WGS84 projection, it should not affect the result.

[Visual example of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrbyL.jpg)

Am I doing it wrong and is there any way of having an actual polygon ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior: operator `&&` means exactly `bounding box intersection`. This is the most general spatial operation and it can use spatial index.

You need an additional filter in a query like the following:

`geoCoordinates && ? AND my_custom_geo_filter(geoCoordinates, ?)`

where in `my_custom_geo_filter` function you can use all the capabilities of JTS library.

By default Ignite does not define any geo-related functions in SQL, so you have to do it manually using `QuerySqlFunction`[1] annotation. See
https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/query/annotations/QuerySqlFunction.html

Comment: Indeed! However I think the custom methods needs to be added in a jar loaded by apache ignite at startup.